# How to filter batch file with pipe?

Tags: windows, batch-file, grep, sh

I am trying to filter (git staged) files and concatenate it.  I am getting error as file not  found. refer [image: screenshot]

```
set List='git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACMR'
set output=
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%List%) do ( 
      (Echo "%%a"| find ".java" set output=!output! "%%a") || (
    REM    set output=!output! "%%a" 
   ))
echo %output%
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show me an example of the input files and what you expect the results to be.

Comment: I am getting  staged files with git command, set List='git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACMR'

Comment: ok, that does not help me very much. So I am not sure if you simply want to use the variable name, or if you actually check the files etc, so please edit your question and update accordingly please.

Comment: I'll get changed files filepath as string and I need to get only files ends with .java

Comment: ok, so you actually run the git command in the loop and want to assign the results to the variables. Are you adding a list of commands in the variable, or is it only the one command?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood what you're doing, it would make it much more efficient if you filtered the results within the parenthesized command instead of the `do` portion:

```batch-file
@Set "ListCommand='git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter^=ACMR ^^^| "%%__AppDir__%%findstr.exe" /L /I /E ".java"'"
@Set "output="
@For /F Delims^= %%G In (%ListCommand%)Do @If Not Defined output (Set output="%%~G")Else Set "output=!output! "%%~G""
@Echo %output%
```

*This assumes that you have delayed expansion enabled, and that none of your returned file names contain exclamation marks. It also assumes that you do not have too many returned filenames, otherwise the size of the environment could be exceeded.*

Comment: This didn't work, I changed to shell file totally. made use of grep in it.

Comment: Apologies @VigneshPushkaran, I made typos in my command above, and have now rectified them. Feel free to try it again!